# Retrieving nth qualifier in hbase using java

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, bigdata

This question is quite out of box but i need it.

In list(collection), we can retrieve the nth element in the list by list.get(i);

similarly is there any method, in hbase, using java API, where i can get the nth qualifier given the row id and ColumnFamily name.

NOTE: I have million qualifiers in single row in single columnFamily.

Comment: Do you have the qualifier name??

Comment: no, there will be many qualifiers. if i pass some index number of qualifier, i should get the respective qualifier?

Comment: We can make it work somehow..But, how are you gonna make sure that the index you are passing corresponds to the desired column?You should have some kind of mapping between the index and the column name. Right??

Comment: Yes, i know column name(column family name) plus i know corresponding rowid. All i need id to extract nth qualifier by specifying column name and its rowid. I've already mentioned it above(... given the row id and ...)

Comment: What's the problem when you already have the column name along with the rowid? However, column family name is not the same as column name. Could you please explain me your use case, if you don't mind. This seems to be an unnecessary operation when you have everything in place.

Comment: Please refer the question which i've asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23627847/retrieve-any-three-random-qualifier-in-hbase-using-java . here, TEST is my table name, 4 is my rowid, "data" is column family, and 108,112,12... are qualifier(grows till million) in the same rowid(4),same column family("data"),). i want to extract let's say 100th qualifier under in 4th rowid,"data" columnFamily. Hope this will get u my use case.?

Comment: @Tariq: Please reply. I'm in need of this

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being unresponsive. Busy with something important. Try this for right now :

```
package org.myorg.hbasedemo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;

public class GetNthColunm {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        HTable table = new HTable(conf, "TEST");
        Get g = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("4"));
        Result r = table.get(g);
        System.out.println("Enter column index :");
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int index = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("index : " + index);
        int count = 0;      
        for (KeyValue kv : r.raw()) {
            if(++count!=index)
                continue;
            System.out.println("Qualifier : "
                    + Bytes.toString(kv.getQualifier()));
            System.out.println("Value : " + Bytes.toString(kv.getValue()));
        }       
        table.close();
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }
}
```

Will let you know if I get a better way to do this.